# Prove Contraction Mapping

Tags: metric-spaces

The following is given:

Eucliden metric $d$, defining the distance between vector $v_1=(x_1,y_1)$ and $v_2=(x_2,y_2)$:

$d(v_1,v_2)=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2 + (y_1-y_2)^2}$

$M $ is a mapping of $\mathbb R^2$ to itself. Given that $v=(x,y)$ in $\mathbb  R$, $M(v)=(1,1)+\beta(x,y). \beta=0.5$

Can you with this example show me how i would prove that $M$ is a contraction mapping?

Answer (score 0):

$$d(Mv_1,Mv_2):=d\left((1,1)+\frac12(x_1,y_1)\,,\,\,(1,1)+\frac12(x_2,y_2)\right)=$$

$$=d\left(\left(1+\frac12x_1\,,\,1+\frac12y_1\right)\,,\,\,\left(1+\frac12x_2\,,\,1+\frac12y_2\right)\right)=$$

$$=\sqrt{\frac14(x_1-x_2)^2+\frac14(y_1-y_2)^2}=\frac12\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}\le$$

$$\le\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}=d\left(v_1\,,\,\,v_2\right)$$